# Why does Mr. Poe cough so much?

Tags: character-analysis, lemony-snicket, a-series-of-unfortunate-events

In the recent adaptation of Lemony Snicket's *A Series of Unfortunate Events*, the character Arthur Poe is portrayed with a consistent cough.  This is never touched on in the Netflix series, but is it explained why he has this cough in the books at all?  If so, why?

Comment: It is my sad duty to inform you that asking for in-universe explanations for ASoUE elements will end in nothing but misery and despair. I'm sorry to have to tell you this. But that is how the story goes.

Comment: The character's name *Poe* evokes comparison with Edgar Allen Poe whose wife died of tuberculosis. Does this suggest a diagnosis of TB for Arthur Poe?

Comment: 4 theories: https://www.popsugar.co.uk/celebrity/Why-Does-Mr-Poe-Cough-Series-Unfortunate-Events-43023056

Answer (score 9):

> The children remembered Mr. Poe because he always had a cold and was
>   constantly excusing himself fromthe table to have a fit of coughing in the next room.

The top quote is from Book 1 (*The Bad Beginning*) and the next is from Book 2 (*The Reptile Room*).

> The driver of the car was Mr. Poe, a family 
>   friend who worked at a bank and always had 
>   a cough.

It seems he is just sickly, and is constantly at a state of having a cold--which seems like a rather unfortunate event to me.  Or he has constant year-round mild allergies and hasn't found a fix for them yet.